# How to verify if method was called with expected argument (java.util.List as an argument) by Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Below you can see an example class of `WorkWithArrayList`. This class has two methods `removeFirstThree` and `insertData`. `removeFirstThree` method gets a `List` as an argument and modifies it, and inserts into database. In `for` loop I showed this modification as if it was removing first element of the `List` of `Integer`s and inserts data on every iteration.

The thing I want to realise is to verify arguments of `insertData` method. But `verify` method checking with only first `verify(workWithArrayList).insertData(expected);` declaration.

```
package test;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

public class MockitoVerifyWithArrayListTest {

    private WorkWithArrayList workWithArrayList;
    private List<Integer> actual;
    private List<Integer> expected;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        workWithArrayList = spy(new WorkWithArrayList());

        actual = new ArrayList<>();
        actual.add(1);
        actual.add(2);
        actual.add(3);
        actual.add(4);
        actual.add(5);
        actual.add(6);

        expected = new ArrayList<>();
        expected.add(1);
        expected.add(2);
        expected.add(3);
        expected.add(4);
        expected.add(5);
        expected.add(6);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        workWithArrayList.removeFirstThree(actual);

        expected.remove(0);
        verify(workWithArrayList).insertData(expected);

        expected.remove(0);
        verify(workWithArrayList).insertData(expected);

        expected.remove(0);
        verify(workWithArrayList).insertData(expected);
    }

    public class WorkWithArrayList {

        public void removeFirstThree(List<Integer> integers) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                integers.remove(0);
                insertData(integers);
            }
        }

        public void insertData(List<Integer> integers) {

        }
    }
}
```

When I run this test I am facing with the following error:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
workWithArrayList.insertData(
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
);
-> at test.MockitoVerifyWithArrayListTest.test(MockitoVerifyWithArrayListTest.java:46)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
workWithArrayList.insertData(
    [4, 5, 6]
);
-> at test.MockitoVerifyWithArrayListTest.test(MockitoVerifyWithArrayListTest.java:43)
```

**Edit:** If we look at javadoc of `Mockito.verify` method, we can see this: 
Arguments passed are compared using `equals()` method.


But variables `actual` and `expected` are equal, and they will remain being equal even when we remove both's first element. I'm interested why this test fails then.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I miss something really essential, you are mixing up things and thus making it harder for yourself to test things.

You see, *modifying* a list and *putting* that list somewhere are two **different** responsibilities. Therefore you forcing both aspects into the same class makes testing hard!

A better approach here: separate concerns. Create a class that does list manipulation. That class can probably be tested without **any** mocking! 
You create a list; give that to the list modify class; and check what comes back. Just asserts required!

And then, when you know that list manipulation works, you only need to test that writing a list to the DB works; and you don't care how the list to write actually looks like!

Answer (score 1):

Mockito doesn't clone or copy the object when storing invocation details, or take any sort of "snapshot"; the value is passed in and Mockito copies the reference. This means that it can be very counter-intuitive to match a real mutable object.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    // expected: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; actual: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    workWithArrayList.removeFirstThree(actual);

    // expected: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; actual: [4, 5, 6]
    // Mockito's invocation list:
    //    three calls to removeFirstThree(actual), where actual is [4, 5, 6],
    //    even though actual had different values during each of the calls!

    expected.remove(0);
    verify(workWithArrayList).insertData(expected);

    expected.remove(0);
    verify(workWithArrayList).insertData(expected);

    expected.remove(0);
    verify(workWithArrayList).insertData(expected);
}
```

Because of this mutable data, it may be very hard to use Mockito to demonstrate correct behavior without resorting to an `Answer` that copies the data (or otherwise detects each of the calls as they happen).